# Applying 'extract a method' refactoring to an async method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, refactoring

'**Extract a method**' is one of the most important and frequently performed refactoring to keep code clean and readable. In many cases, we can apply it automatically and safely with all modern IDEs.

My question is what is the best approach to apply this to async methods in C# (and other languages with *async* keyward such as JavaScript, TypeScript etc.)

As an example, suppose we have a lengthy async method which can be logically grouped and decomposed into separate methods like below:

```
private async Task StartWriting()
{

    if (IsCreatingNewDir) 
    {  
        SaveFile();

        var writingSpec = _writingSpec.Model!;

        if (!OkToStartWriting(writingSpec)) return;

        await _jobQueue.EnterJob(writingSpec);
    }
    else
    {
        if (!OkToStartWritingFromExistingDir()) return;

        try
        {
            await _jobQueue.EnterJobFromExistingJobDir(Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(FilePath))!);
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            DialogManager.ShowError(Localize("NoConversionResultInJobDir"));
            Logger.LogError(ex, "Invalid job directory.");
        }
    }
}
```

If I just apply it with Visual studio (with resharper), each of the extracted fragments becomes also an async method.

```cs
public async Task StartWriting()
{

    if (IsCreatingNewDir)
    {
        await StartWritingFromScratch();
    }
    else
    {
        await StartWritingFromExistingDir();
    }
}
        
private async Task StartWritingFromScratch()
{
    SaveFile();

    var writingSpec = _writingSpec.Model!;

    if (!OkToStartWriting(writingSpec)) return;


    await _jobQueue.EnterJob(writingSpec);
}


private async Task StartWritingFromExistingDir()
{
    if (!OkToStartWritingFromExistingDir()) return;

    try
    {
        await _jobQueue.EnterJobFromExistingJobDir(Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(FilePath))!);
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
    {
        DialogManager.ShowError(Localize("NoConversionResultInJobDir"));
        Logger.LogError(ex, "Invalid job directory.");
    }
```

This is OK, as the logic is the same and async method can call another async method. However, considering that async method is really a syntactic sugar and it is converted to rather complex code under the hood, I wonder if it's additional overhead is legitimate just to keep code readable. I think that the original refactoring to normal methods, hidden assumption is that method call overhead is rather small and negligible.

Another option I can think of is to extract each fragment as a synchronous method returning a Task like this:

```
// Extract fragment as a regular synchronous method returning Task which is awaitable.
private Task StartWritingFromExistingDir()
{

    if (!OkToStartWritingFromExistingDir()) return Task.CompletedTask;

    try
    {
        return _jobQueue.EnterJobFromExistingJobDir(Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(FilePath))!);
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
    {
        DialogManager.ShowError(Localize("NoConversionResultInJobDir"));
        Logger.LogError(ex, "Invalid job directory.");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

The code looks a bit noisier as I have to return Task explicitly, but I think it performs better and in most cases easier to debug and test.

Is there a generally agreed known best practice for doing this refactoring to async methods?

Comment: *I think it performs better* - How many nanoseconds does it save?

Comment: I agree that in practice the overhead doesn't matter in most of the time. But my question is that how the language designer thought about this refactoring, and how clever the compiler is to optimize performance. Small method is almost always better for clean code, but it seems it doesn't apply equally well for async methods.

Comment: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about the additional overhead, modify the parent method like this:

```
public Task StartWriting()
{
    if (IsReadOnly)
    {
        return StartWritingFromExistingDir();
    }
    else
    {
        return StartWritingFromScratch();
    }
}
```

Now you are not creating any of the additional `async` overhead.